# HTTPServer: "Cannot assign requested address" on localhost vs 127.0.0.1

Tags: python, sockets, tcp, ipv6

With the below Python 3 code:

```
from http.server import HTTPServer, SimpleHTTPRequestHandler
s = HTTPServer(('localhost', 0), SimpleHTTPRequestHandler)
```

I get the following error:

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "repro.py", line 2, in <module>
    s = HTTPServer(('localhost', 0), SimpleHTTPRequestHandler)
  File "/usr/lib/python3.6/socketserver.py", line 453, in __init__
    self.server_bind()
  File "/usr/lib/python3.6/http/server.py", line 136, in server_bind
    socketserver.TCPServer.server_bind(self)
  File "/usr/lib/python3.6/socketserver.py", line 467, in server_bind
    self.socket.bind(self.server_address)
OSError: [Errno 99] Cannot assign requested address
```

I've noticed that 3 things will prevent this from happening:

1. Disabling WiFi.
2. Switching to a different WiFi network (from my home router to tethering on my phone).
3. Changing `'localhost'` in the code to `'127.0.0.1'`.

So my question is, what's going wrong here? Why does this code fail when it does?

P.S. [Here is ip a's output when connected to my home router](https://gist.github.com/kerrickstaley/b1fe713144f8506cdf7ab4b6bbf10baf), and [here's its output when tethering](https://gist.github.com/kerrickstaley/9c16dcac4d7cde5313c3ce46c81da2ba).

Comment: Have you tried other available port? Port 0 is a system or well-known port as describe [here](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Registered_port).

Comment: If changing from `localhost` to `127.0.0.1` fixes it, it sounds like a DNS problem. What does `dig localhost` show?

Comment: Your `ip a` output is missing the important bits, i.e. the interface `lo`. Please add this information.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I believe the issue was that the DNS service on my home WiFi network was not returning the correct information for localhost. I ended up working around this issue by hardcoding the address as `127.0.0.1`.

Answer (score 0):

I get the same error after i change the ip of my vps, so the `ifconfig` will output somethings like :

```sh
lo: flags=73<UP,LOOPBACK,RUNNING>  mtu 65536
        loop  txqueuelen 1000  (Local Loopback)
        RX packets 0  bytes 0 (0.0 B)
        RX errors 0  dropped 0  overruns 0  frame 0
        TX packets 0  bytes 0 (0.0 B)
        TX errors 0  dropped 0 overruns 0  carrier 0  collisions 0
```

the `lo` interface has no ip address. If everything is ok, this ip address should be `127.0.0.1`, the normal output is something like:

```
lo: flags=73<UP,LOOPBACK,RUNNING>  mtu 65536
        inet 127.0.0.1  netmask 255.0.0.0
        inet6 ::1  prefixlen 128  scopeid 0x10<host>
        loop  txqueuelen 1000  (Local Loopback)
        RX packets 0  bytes 0 (0.0 B)
        RX errors 0  dropped 0  overruns 0  frame 0
        TX packets 0  bytes 0 (0.0 B)
        TX errors 0  dropped 0 overruns 0  carrier 0  collisions 0
```

I'm not sure what cause this error, but **this error has nothing to do with the port, but with the ip address**, you may checkout the output of `ifconfig`.

Answer (score -1):

i think, you cant listen in 0 port.
I tried in node js and SocketTest. They 2 can(and cant) listen but/and cant connect to the port. Its mean it can and cant both do that.
may this link help you 
https://unix.stackexchange.com/questions/180492/is-it-possible-to-connect-to-tcp-port-0 
https://docs.python.org/2/library/simplehttpserver.html

Comment: I don't understand why this answer is downvoted, it's the correct one. You can't generally listen on port 0. 

And unless you are running your python snippet as root you will not be able to bind port below 1024. 

So you should try with this: 
    s = HTTPServer(('localhost', 8080), SimpleHTTPRequestHandler)

Comment: @opentokix Using `('localhost', 0)` will assign a random, open, unprivileged port.